# How to get the audit, file beat and metric beat logs in kubernetes cluster using EFK stack?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, fluentd

I am trying to get the audit, file beat, and metric beat logs together using Fluentd in Kibana dashboard of my kubernetes cluster. I am able to get the audit, file beat and metric beat log separately as specific indexes like filebeat-*, auditbeat-* and metricbeat-* in my Kibana dashboard.

Could anybody suggest me? Is there any possibility to get the above 3 types of logs within a single index?

Comment: send them to logstash instead and configure logstasht o create a single index pattern for of logs

Comment: Why would you combine 3 different Beats into one index? It will only explode the number of fields and potentially cause mapping issues if the same field name has different data types in different Beats. If it's just for retrieving the data, you can always use a wildcard in your access pattern or define an alias pointing to multiple indices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming you are talking about an EFK stack and not an ELK stack. In your Fluentd configs you can have something like this:

```
<match *.**>
  type copy
  <store>
    type elasticsearch
    host localhost
    port 9200
    include_tag_key true
    tag_key @log_name
    logstash_format true
    flush_interval 10s
    index_name fluentd.common.%Y%m%d
  </store>
</match>
```

They will all go to the same index `fluentd.common.%Y%m%d`, as opposed to having `index_name fluentd.${tag}.%Y%m%d`.

Comment: If you want pod, deployment info, etc, Prometheus is a better solution, but that's another question. EFK is more suited for logs.

Comment: Hello Rico, Thanks for your quick response. sorry for the confusion. yes, I am talking about EFK. Here is the link https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-elasticsearch which i was followed. I am able to get the logs of kubernetes pods.but unable to get the events information like pods, stateful sets and deployments were created (or) updated (or) deleted. I enabled audit configuration while i was initializing the kubeadm cluster. Is it necessary to run audit, filebeat and metric beat daemons on top of my kubernetes cluster?

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do with those tools. (filebeat, metricbeat)

Comment: ok, Can you please guide me to get the audit logs of kubernetes cluster using fluentd?

Comment: Read up on this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/

Comment: I already gone through that. Is it necessary to run audit beat daemon set or it automatically get the logs?

Comment: Not really, you can also use a fluentd sidecar or simple `tail` sidecar: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/

Comment: Thank you Rico. I will try and Let you know.